# How to retrieve non-contiguous cell collections from strings in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I tried to `=SUM(INDIRECT("B4,B6"))` but it doesn't work. How to do that?

Comment: What formula are you using the `INDIRECT` range with?  Remember, that returns those two exact cells as a single range, not two separate ranges.

Comment: In pt-BR I use `=SOMA(INDIRETO("B4;B6"))`

Comment: @Breakthrough edited to provide your answer.

Comment: the `SUM` function only takes continuous cell ranges as its arguments.

Comment: @Breakthrough: `SUM` can take not only continuous but also discrete ranges as its arguments.

Comment: @Mehper C. Palavuzlar *each argument* has to be a continuous range.  What you posted in your answer further proves my point, since you did not specify a non-continuous range for any argument, but rather, they are all continuous.

Comment: @Breakthrough: Oh, I see your point. Of course. I agree that _each argument_ has to be a continuous range. What I meant was, the totality of arguments inside the parentheses of `SUM` can form either a continuous (i.e. `B1:B6`) or a discrete (i.e. `B1,B3,B5`) series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works this way:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("B4"),INDIRECT("B6"))
```